# First item ListView ago ActionBar

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-actionbar

I thought that the first item was not being added to the list, but I noticed that being added, because when I put a marginTop `android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"` the ListView item appeared. **What should I do to fix this?** 
 
Without attribute `android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"` the first item disappears, it is behind the ActionBar.

[image: Genymotion Emulator image]

**activity_settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.simplerecorder.preferences.SettingsActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listSettings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_separator"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**in SettingsActivity.java**

```
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listSettings);

        String[] titles = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        String[] descs = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.descs);

        listAdapter = new SettingsAdapter(context, titles, descs);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        prefsDialogs.dgColorPicker();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        prefsDialogs.dgNotify();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        prefsDialogs.dgFolderPicker();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**arrays.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="titles">
        <item>Cor do widget</item>
        <item>Onde salvar</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="descs">
        <item>Mude a cor do widget aqui</item>
        <item>Escolha a pasta de sua preferencia</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: That is normal behaviour. Nothing to fix. The Toolbar is simply a sheet above your other UI elements. If you want your other UI elements to be shown below it, you need to tell them. By setting marginTop, or using RelativeLayout and set below the Toolbar.

Comment: Thanks I am using RelativeLayout.LayoutParams and marginTop, but I thought it was a mistake in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Writing this as an answer to complete this question (and for future reference of Stack Overflow users).

That is normal behaviour. There is nothing to fix.

The Toolbar is simply a sheet above your other UI elements.

If you want your other UI elements to be shown below it, you need to tell them. By setting `android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`, or using `RelativeLayout` and set below the `Toolbar` `android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"`.